# How to save an image having use Otsu's filter

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, image-processing

Ok I am a bit confused with the file format I should use to apply this filter, and the file format I should use to save the image.

Here is my code

```
img1 = cv2.imread('I1_fil2D.png',1)
skdemo.imshow_with_histogram(img1);

from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu
thresh = threshold_otsu(rgb2gray(img1))
bw_img1 = rgb2gray(img1) > thresh

plt.imshow(bw_img1)
```

I used `rgb2gray()` command because `threshold_otsu()` need a grayscale image as input. I tried to use `cv2.imwrite('bw1.jpg',bw_img1)`, but it says: `TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img'` (I also tried `bw_img1 = np.array(bw_img1)` before this command and nothing changed). Moreover, I tried `imsave`, but it also doesn't work because I used `cv2` for thresholding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has an issue and that is why `cv2.imwrite()` can't save the image.

When you do `bw_img1 = rgb2gray(img1) > thresh` the output is a True/False matrix, since it is not numerical `cv2.imwrite()` won't save it.

Remember, `cv2.imread()` read RGB images as BGR, so i corrected it.

I fixed the code and now it works.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu

img1 = cv2.imread('myimage.png',1)

#image from BGR to GRAYSCALE
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#get the threshold
thresh = threshold_otsu(gray_image)
#create a copy of the gray image
bw_img1 = np.copy(gray_image)
#apply the binarization
bw_img1[bw_img1 < thresh] = 0
bw_img1[bw_img1 >= thresh] = 255

plt.imshow(bw_img1)

cv2.imwrite("otsu.png", bw_img1)
```

Comment: If it was helpful, could you mark it as correct answer, thanks.